# Visual C++ debug runtime faster than release runtime?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I'm trying to do some performance tests. I found that my code linked with Visual C++(2010) debug runtime seems to run faster than it linked with release runtime.

I can reproduce the problem with very simple code snippet and build commandline:

```
#include <sys/timeb.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>


int main() {
    unsigned int *a= new unsigned int[100000000];
    unsigned int v = 0xaabbccdd;
    timeb start, end;

    ftime(&start);
    clock_t start_cycle = clock();

    for (register int i=0; i<100000000; i++) {
      a[i] += v;
    }   

    clock_t end_cycle = clock();
    ftime(&end);

    printf ("elapsed time: %d ms\n", ((end.time - start.time)*1000 + 
                                       end.millitm - start.millitm));
    printf ("cycles: %d\n", end_cycle - start_cycle);

    delete a;
    return end_cycle - start_cycle;
}
```

$ cl /O2 /MT test.cc

elapsed time: 176 ms

$ cl /O2 /MTd test.cc

elapsed time: 88 ms

$ cl /MT test.cc

elapsed time: 523 ms

$ cl /MTd test.cc

elapsed time: 480 ms

Both generate same assembly code when I add /Fa option.

Building it with MingW32 g++ -O3 gives me similar result of release version:

$ g++ -O3 test.cc

elapsed time: 172 ms

I wonder how the VC debug runtime could be so fast. Does it optimize/omit something I'm not aware of?

Comment: btw, what is the purpose of using debug runtime if you don't compile your code with debug points?

Comment: Why do you think it should be faster in release? The runtime isn't doing anything at all, except `ftime` and `printf`, which are outside the loop. So the difference is accounted for by a one-off cost. The one one-hundredth of a second difference could be accounted for by a single additional page fault.  Probably the difference is the release does ALSR or something and the debug doesn't.

Comment: @user1810087 just curious about what happened in the loop. This is absolutely not an issue to my project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
unsigned int *a= new unsigned int[100000000];
```

You are making a traditional bench-mark mistake, you start the timer too late.  On a demand-paged virtual memory operating system, like Windows, that statement only allocates address space.  Just numbers to the processor, one for each 4096 bytes in the allocation.  It does **not** allocate physical memory, just virtual memory.

That doesn't happen until later, when you actually start accessing the array elements.  That generates a *page fault*, the demand-paged feature, forcing the operating system to map the address space to RAM.  Your program will generate 97657 page faults (100000000 * 4 / 4096).

The difference between the debug and the release builds is exactly *when* those page faults occur.  In your release build, they occur inside the for() loop and their cost is included in your measurement.  As they should be.

But when you build with /MTd or /MDd then you'll use the debug allocator.  Which [initializes allocated heap blocks](http://www.nobugs.org/developer/win32/debug_crt_heap.html) with a bit pattern that's likely to get your program to crash when you invoke undefined behavior and use uninitialized memory.  That initialization trips the same page faults.  But occur *before* you started the timer.  So your measurement is off, it doesn't include the memory mapping cost.

You'll need to start your timer before the allocation to compare apples and oranges.

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks. I added a memset() after the memory allocation call to force page faults. Then the numbers are equal between debug and release runtimes.