Is C++ new memory in physical RAM after allocation?
new[] gives us consecutive memory.
C++23 draft N4928, chapter 6.7.5.5.2 (2) "Allocation functions", emphasis mine:

An allocation function attempts to allocate the requested amount of storage. If it is successful, it returns
the address of the start of a block of storage whose length in bytes is at least as large as the requested size.

Does the C++ specification specify whether that block of memory is actually in physical RAM after the allocation, or may it be in virtual RAM only and thus completely or partially paged to disk?
Origin of this question is a discussion in the comments of this question.

Usually the distinction between virtual and physical memory does not occur at the application level, so I would be surprised if there's any discussion of that in the C++ draft at all.

Nothing in the C++ standard specifies that. It has a very abstract idea of hardware. However based on recent questions here I can say that, in practice, the memory returned by new may be in virtual memory. Also 'in virtual memory' does not imply 'paged to disk', at least not in Windows.

The C++ Standard targets an Abstract machine which does not concern itself with physical/virtual memory. "...The semantic descriptions in this document define a parameterized nondeterministic abstract machine. This document places no requirement on the structure of conforming implementations. In particular, they need not copy or emulate the structure of the abstract machine. Rather, conforming implementations are required to emulate (only) the observable behavior of the abstract machine as explained below...."

Where the memory is actually located is up to the OS not to C++ itself.

@PepijnKramer that's also my understanding. It could even be in the cloud, if Microsoft decided to implement that as an alternative to paging to disk.

And when it comes to the OS, Linux can under circumstances agree to even unreasonable allocations that cannot be satisfied using all available memory. The allocation will seemingly succeed, you'll get a bunch on non-resident pages and your program will only get killed later if it tries to write to too many of them.

Also realize that some OS's and/or hardware don't even support virtual memory, and your C++ code would still look the same. What I am more curious about is why do you want to know? Is it because of some performance issues or just curiousity? :)

@PepijnKramer: it's mostly because of the new comment of Peter stating that two std::vectors (the old vector before reallocation and the new vector) must both be in RAM. I doubt that.

It would definitely be more efficient to have both in physical RAM at the same time. But AFAIK that is not how memory paging works, if there is a pagefault a page gets swapped by another page (according to some strategy)... so it may well be that after copying both vectors are in RAM (if RAM is big enough).  So copoying may slow down to the point of being unusable due to trashing... but as long as there is enough virtual memory I don't see why copying would fail. (But again how it really works is OS specific)

@ThomasWeller they don't have to be both in physical RAM. Peter is wrong there. They both must fit in free addressable space, which would usually be user-addressable virtual memory but doesn't have to be. In that DOS example you mentioned, in tiny memory model std::vector would fail to resize before it hits even 32K in size, even though its max_size() would probably indicate 64K of maximum usable space.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/24631743/17034

C++ does not really deal with physical machines. It targets some abstract machine that just has some sort of uniform memory. For C++ standard, there is no such thing as physical or virtual memory, so it cannot specify either way. So this is the answer to your question as asked.
Now, if you were to ask "will my new[] allocated memory be allocated in physical memory in reality?", the answer would be "it depends on the environment". For example, your C++ program could target some sort of microcontrontroller like ARM Cortex M3, which has no MMU to speak of. In this case, new[] would give you a chunk of contiguous physical memory at the address you are given (and there is no concept of virtual memory there at all, so your question makes no sense in that environment). You could target DOS, in which case you also get a contiguous physical memory at the address you are given (unless your program runs under VDM of some sort, like in Windows, in which case it doesn't get physical memory). You could target some OS that has MMU but no paging or on-demand allocation. In that case, you'll get contiguous virtual memory which is backed by physical memory - but that physical memory might not be contiguous, and you won't know its address. Finally, you could target some "usual" OS environment with MMU and paging, like Linux - in which case you'll get virtual memory which might not be backed by physical memory (in case of Linux which has on-demand paging - you'll definitely not get physical memory for most of that returned block of virtual memory)

In old DOS (not the 32 bit extended one) you could not even allocate more than one page at a time. So your physical memory was larger than you could allocate (in one time) in practice. So yes hardware limitiations can "leak" through

Well, you technically could. There could have been an implementation which would use 32 bit size_t, and huge pointers by default, and fmemcpy for memcpy, fmalloc for malloc etc. I think watcom did had a huge memory model? Just usually this wasn't done for performance reasons. Hardware implementation concerns do end up not only in particular implementations of C++, but even shape the standard itself (all the restrictions on pointers are due to them possibly being segmented, or e.g. when did signed overflow became legal and why was it illegal before?)

Yes I remember the bigger memory models... even bugs in them (e.g. the offset was still 16 bits in one compiler). And ofcourse hardware imposes a lot of the C++ standard, most UB is related to that too. And watcom on x386 allowed you to switch to 32 bit mode... but that was tricky with interrupt handlers... Haha those "good" old days ;) (where  you could at least still reasona bout how memory/CPU really worked)

Terminology note: MMU -> Memory Management Unit.
